# R count the occurrences of row string values in another row string

Tags: r

In R, looking for a function to count the occurrences of one row value (complete string) in another row value
eg: data table df

```
df$SerachingFor  df$Target                               df$SearchTermOccurrencesInTarget (required field)
Machine rowing   machine rowing has two values           1
handy tools      handy tools, we have many handy tools   2
plans            home plans, garden plans, DIY plans     3
hospital         home ideas                              0
```

appreciate your time

Comment: Ohh, looks like someone don't like my question but getting an error on trying with below answer as Error in stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach with `stringr` library's function. Note, I converted both columns to all lower case letters as your example implies case insensitive match.

```
library(stringr)
df$SerachingFor <- tolower(df$SerachingFor)
df$Target <- tolower(df$Target)
df$SearchTermOccurrencesInTarget <- str_count(df$Target, df$SerachingFor)
df
    SerachingFor                                Target SearchTermOccurrencesInTarget
1 machine rowing         machine rowing has two values                             1
2    handy tools  handy tools we have many handy tools                             2
3          plans     home plans garden plans DIY plans                             3
4       hospital                            home ideas                             0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however getting error as Error in stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX) - any help here please

Comment: You could do it without changing the original data, and saving a couple of lines of code, with `with(df, str_count(tolower(Target), tolower(SerachingFor)))`.

Comment: Richard, thank you for the answer, however getting an error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX Error in stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX).  Any help please

Comment: Are your columns read as factors? If so, change the data frame columns to `as.character`. There could also be some characters in your fuller data set that are causing issue. I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps you can print the unique characters in that column and see what might be going on.